# Ampscript Code Issue unable to send the email to subscriber

Tags: ampscript

Could you please help me on below amp script code unable to send the email with transactional products with one orderID, as it is correctly generating the record in preview test.

Got the error from salesforce support team case no:19644818

```
%%[
var @rows,@row,@row1,@rowCount,@numRowsToReturn,@i,@prevOrderNumber,@OrderID,@ProductID,@ProductName

set @OrderID = AttributeValue("OrderID")
outputline(concat("",@OrderID))
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Order_Details_Copy",@numRowsToReturn, "OrderID", "OrderID", @OrderID)

set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then


    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
         var @rows1,@row2

         set @row = row(@rows,@i)
         set @ProductID = field(@row,"ProductID")         
         set @rows1= Lookup('Product_Details','ProductName','ProductID',@ProductID)
         set @rows2= Lookup('Product_Details','Milk','ProductID',@ProductID)

         outputline(concat("Product Name:",@rows1)) 
         outputline(concat("Milk:",@rows2))   
    next @i

else
    outputline(concat("No transactionsList rows found"))
endif

]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

If it shows the result correctly on the preview test, then the issue is about the relationship between the list you want to send and your subscriber database. I mean, if the contacts are not in your database already with a defined email address, then it cannot be sent even if the preview is fine.

Comment: Yes, you are right but i have done the data extension relationship also raise case to salesforce team as above question you will find the use case number.

Comment: Also the Issue is resolved,I am not using that text area code in email template so it shows me error of "prase in html" that's why it is not sending the email to that users or customer with displaying the one orders with multiple products in that email. Thanks Selim Sevim for your reply.